# Access to Service Provider by User Store

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I recently deployed WSO2 Identity Server 5.0 at our institution. Now, we want to add more services, but we want to limit access by user population. Since we already have secondary user stores with these populations (Students and Employees), I was hoping to leverage for access.

How can I restrict access to service providers based on secondary user store membership?

Comment: how did you solve your problem? Could you implement role-based authorization?

Comment: We have not been able to solve the problem with IS; we had to do check in downstream systems instead.

Comment: :/ Thanks. I think there is a way with API-Manager